# Using space left by siblings in a row - MediaQuery.of(): context is null

Tags: flutter, text, layout, row, ellipsis

I'm trying to arrange two `text`s in a `row`. The second text is only a few words, but the first can be very long. My goal is to show the second text fully, and fill the remaining space with the first. If the first widget is too wide, I want to truncate it with an ellipsis.

Expected layout:
[image: expected layout]

My code is

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
            child: Text("Really really really long long long teeeeext",
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - MediaQuery.of(key.currentContext).size.width),
        Text("short text", key: key)
      ],
    );

  }
}
```

It fails with `The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]): I/flutter (28083): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart': Failed assertion: line 810 pos 12: 'context != I/flutter (28083): null': is not true.`
I guess because the Flutter engine hasn't started rendering the "short text" widget yet, so it's size is unknown at this time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaQuery.of(context).size` isn't available during build phase. While building the widget, sizes aren't calculated yet.

However you don't need `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to implement the layout. Instead, you can simply wrap left text with `Expanded`. Then it will take all remaining space (total width minus right text width).

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        "Really really really long long long teeeeext 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123",
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      "short text",
    ),
  ],
)
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to init your second Text Widget like `Text _secondText=Text("short text")`? So Flutter should already know its content when you use your first widget. You can give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error (code: https://hastebin.com/vumerusicu.js).

Comment: So, you can try another solution: use the property `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl` of the Row Widget, which inverts the widgets from right to left. So in your code first render the short text widget, then as second child you can render the long text. Like this: https://pastebin.com/VipWYv7D

Comment: Same error message :(   (And the rtl direction causes that the second widget goes first)

Comment: I came up with this solution. Just wrap your Container with a Flexible widget, then mantain the Row property rtl to let your second text appear before the first. And remove the width and overflow properties of the Container. Here is what I used and worked for me: https://hastebin.com/donuraqamo.js